# How do I get my SUV through that ring?

Tags: crackdown

If anyone has played "Crackdown", then you're aware of those purple, ring shaped "stunt markers" floating in various locations around the city.  If anyone is still familiar with the game, can you give me an idea of how to get to the one directly outside of, and above the tunnel leading from the Agency to the Corridor (Shai-Gen controlled zone)?
I've tried everything I can think of, with no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a 4 star SUV, and you need to bunny hop after an S curve at the end of the tunnel.

[Source (including video)](http://www.candiedskull.com/crackdown/stunts/30.html)

Comment: Yeah that worked.  I didn't realize you could bunny hop with the level 4 SUV.  Thanks!